# Объясните код С++ реверс строки

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Программа выводит текст в обратном порядке. Можете пожалуйста поподробнее объяснить как она работает.

```c
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void reverse(char *c) {  
  if (c[0]=='\0') 
    return; 
  else { 
    reverse(&c[1]); 
    cout<<c[0];
  }
}

int main() {  
   char s[20];
   cout<<"Введите текст: ";
   cin>>s; 
   cout<<"Реверс: ";
   reverse(s);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Эту функцию нельзя назвать полноценным реверсом строки, так как она не возвращает реверсированную строку, а только выводит ее в стандартный поток вывода.

Comment: Сразу стало понятно как работает.

Comment: а я пока и не объяснял.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что делает функция reverse:

1. Начнем с начала

   `if (c[0]=='\0') 
       return;`

Если полученная ею строка состоит только из терминального символа - просто выходит. Мы добрались до конца строки, делать ничего не надо. Это условие остановки рекурсии

2. Запуск рекурсии

   `else {
        reverse(&c[1]);`

Вызывает саму себя с новой строкой, из которой удален первый символ.

3. Формирование вывода:

   `cout<<c[0];
   }`

Здесь происходит вывод первого символа полученной строки.

Как все это, в итоге, работает.

Получив строку, функция вызывает саму себя с обрезанной строкой до тех пор, пока не получит строку, содержащую только терминальный символ. После этого происходит выход из последнего вызова. При этом попадаем в предпоследнюю вызванную копию функции. Она получила на вход строку из одного (последнего) начальной символа и терминального символа. Именно этот последний вызов она и выведет в поток, после чего вернет управление вызвавшей ее функции.

Та, в свою очередь, напечатает первый символ полученной ею строки, то есть предпоследний символ исходной строки, и вернет управление предыдущей функции. Так и будет происходить посимвольная печать и возврат до тех пор, пока не дойдет дело до первого экземпляра функции reverse, которая напечатает первый символ строки и закончит работу.

Еще раз повторюсь: это не полноценный реверс, так как реверсированная строка нигде не сохраняется, кроме как на экране. С ней невозможно дальше работать.

Comment: Спасибо. 3 часть - то что надо.

Answer (score 0):

Она вызывает себя для следующего символа, пока не дойдёт до нуля. Далее будут выводится символы исходной строки в обратном порядке. Данная функция, возможно, иллюстрирует работу стека, туда по очереди заносятся ссылки на функцию с аргументами, а затем вызываются в обратном порядке, потому, что стек работает по принципу первым зашёл, последним вышел.

Comment: Она демонстрирует построение рекурсивных функций.

Answer (score 0):

Со строкой можно дальше работать, достаточно только перенаправить `std::cout` в нужное место (`std::stringstream`, например)

Comment: Вот именно - перенаправить.  Я же не сказал,  что все это совершенно неправильно.  Но для того,  чтобы получить реверсированную строку,  надо предпринимать дополнительные усилия.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов "С ней невозможно дальше работать." неправда

Comment: Правда.  В том виде,  в каком функция представлена в коде ТС - реверсированной строки не существует.  Она есть только в стандартном потоке вывода.  Чтобы ее суметь получить,  нужно либо переписывать функцию,  либо перенаправлять потоки ДО вызова функции.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов если я могу перенаправить поток до вызова функции из вопроса (никак не меняя саму функцию), извлечь реверсированную строку из перенаправленного места, то значит могу с ней работать. У вас написано, что работать нельзя вообще. Про перенаправление ничего не сказано.

Comment: не вижу смысла спорить дальше. Сделать можно много чего,  но я рассуждал только о том коде,  который представил ТС.  А написание функций, требующие подобной подготовки перед свои вызовом - весьма плохая идея.  Это гордится для учебных заданий,  но малопртменимо в реальных проектах.